# Inheritance with Nodes in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm writing a doubly linked list in C++ and have a class `Node` which I'm using for a singly linked list. Below shows the definition of the class.

> Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template <class T>
class Node {
    public:
        Node<T>() { next = nullptr; } 
        Node<T>(T init) { data = init; next = nullptr; }

        void setData(T newData) { data = newData; }
        void setNext(Node<T> *nextNode) { next = nextNode; }

        const T getData() { return data; }
        Node<T> *getNext() { return next; }
    private:
        T data;
        Node<T> *next;
};

#endif
```

Obviously the main difference between a singly linked list and doubly linked list is a pointer to the previous `Node`, so I'm trying to inherit everything from the `Node` class in a new class and simply add a `prev` attribute:

> DoublyLinkedList.h

```
#ifndef DOUBLY_LINKEDLIST_H
#define DOUBLY_LINKEDLIST_H

#include "Node.h"

template <class T>
class DLLNode : public Node {
    public:
        // Inherit default constructor from Node and set prev to nullptr;
        DLLNode<T>() : Node<T>(), prev() {}
        // Inherit constructor from Node and set prev to nullptr;
        DLLNode<T>(T init) : Node<T>(init), prev() {}

        Node<T> *getPrev() { return prev; }
    private:
        Node<T> *prev;
};

/*
    TODO: Implement doubly linked list class
*/

#endif
```

My driver is, simply, the following:

> driver.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DoublyLinkedList.h"

int main() 
{
    DLLNode<int> test;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get the following errors:

```
./DoublyLinkedList.h:7:24: error: expected class name
class DLLNode : public Node {
                       ^
./DoublyLinkedList.h:9:18: error: type 'Node<int>' is not a direct or virtual base of 'DLLNode<int>'
                DLLNode<T>() : Node<T>(), prev() {}
                               ^~~~~~~
driver.cc:6:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'DLLNode<int>::DLLNode' requested here
        DLLNode<int> test;
```

I don't understand why the class `Node` isn't being recognized as a class as my compiler has claimed by the first error. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

My compiler is `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`

Comment: `class DLLNode : public Node<T> {`

Comment: In your example, `Node` is a templated class. That is why compiler cannot recognize it!
Try `Node<T>`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I didn't know the template had to be included. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the template type parameter to your templated base class, when inheriting:

```
template <typename T>
class DLLNode : public Node<T> {
                        // ^^^
   // ...
};
```