# How to construct template hierarchy for singly and doubly list nodes c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I just want to implement two types of nodes(only nodes):
A node for singly linked list and a node class for doubly linked list.
The obvious solution would be to define two separate classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct SinglyNode
{
    using node_pointer = SinglyNode<T>*;
    SinglyNode(T data = T{}, node_pointer next = nullptr)
        : m_data{ data },
        m_next{ next }
    {}
    T m_data;
    node_pointer m_next;
};

template <typename T>
struct DoublyNode
{
    using node_pointer = DoublyNode<T>*;
    DoublyNode(T data = T{}, node_pointer prev = nullptr, node_pointer next = nullptr)
        : m_data{ data },
        m_prev { prev },
        m_next{ next }
    {}
    T m_data;
    node_pointer m_prev;
    node_pointer m_next;
};
```

I know that DoublyNode and SinglyNode both have data, and link to the next node(nodes aren`t of the same type, SinglyNode::m_next is of type SinglyNode* and DoublyNode::m_next is of type DoublyNode*),
in addition DoublyNode also has link to previous node.

But how can I make a hierarchy to erase/minimize code duplicate so that user could use the derived class member without the need to dynamic_cast to derived node?

Note: A code snippet or a few hints will be sufficient for me.

Comment: "*nodes aren't of the same type*" You'll need to clarify this. The templates you posted have nodes of the same type, since for example `node_pointer = SinglyNode<T>*;`.

Comment: @dxiv Edited !!

Comment: You could derive `struct DoublyNode : public SinglyNode<T>` like is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338428/inheritance-with-nodes-in-c) for example. Or do it more elegantly with CRTP as in the just posted answer. If that's what you meant by "*use the derived class member without the need to dynamic_cast*" then you could have made it more clear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CRTP, you might do something like:

```
template <typename Derived, typename T>
struct SinglyNodeCRTP
{
    using node_pointer = Derived*;
    SinglyNodeCRTP(T data = T{}, node_pointer next = nullptr)
        : m_data{ data },
        m_next{ next }
    {}
    T m_data;
    node_pointer m_next;
};


template <typename T>
struct SinglyNode : SinglyNodeCRTP<SinglyNode<T>, T>
{
    using SinglyNodeCRTP::SinglyNodeCRTP;
};

template <typename T>
struct DoublyNode : SinglyNodeCRTP<DoublyNode<T>, T>
{
    using node_pointer = typename SinglyNodeCRTP<DoublyNode<T>, T>::node_pointer;
    DoublyNode(T data = T{}, node_pointer prev = nullptr, node_pointer next = nullptr)
        : SinglyNodeCRTP<DoublyNode<T>, T>{ data , prev },
        m_prev{ prev }
    {}
    node_pointer m_prev;
};
```

Comment: Why we need this ```using SinglyNodeCRTP::SinglyNodeCRTP;``` ?

Comment: [Inherit constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors). Alternatively, you might do as for `DoublyNode`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn`t know about CRTP and "constructor inheriting".

Answer (score 0):

Final code after getting the answers to my questions.

```
      template <typename N, typename T>
      struct node_base {
        T m_value;
        N* m_next;
        node_base(T value = T{}, N* next = T{})
            : m_value{ value },
            m_next{ next }
        {}
      };

      template <typename T>
      struct snode : public node_base<snode<T>, T>
      {
          using node_base::node_base;
      };

      template <typename T>
      struct dnode : public node_base<dnode<T>, T>
      {
        using node_type = dnode<T>;
        dnode(T value = T{}, node_type* prev = nullptr, node_type* next = nullptr)
            : node_base<node_type, T>{ value, next },
            m_prev{prev}
        {}
        dnode<T>* m_prev;
      };
```